# Data in Gremlin Table into subgraph

Tags: gremlin

I am trying to make a subgraph of a graph that I have previously loaded into gremlin. I was able to get all the nodes that I need into a gremlin table, but cannot seem to get them from the table to create the subgraph. I believe that if i can loop through the table and extract the verticies then I can create a subgraph and call addVertex to add them to the graph. My gremlin table looks like this:[image]

I have tried looping through the table and just printing to see if I could traverse it using the following code, but as shown it just returned null and quit
`gremlin> for (x=0; x<t.size(); x=x+1)

gremlin> t[x][0]

==>null`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Check out the API for Table in Pipes:

http://www.tinkerpop.com/docs/javadocs/pipes/2.3.0/com/tinkerpop/pipes/util/structures/Table.html

Here's some examples of accessing the table:

```
gremlin> g = TinkerGraphFactory.createTinkerGraph()
==>tinkergraph[vertices:6 edges:6]
gremlin> t=new Table();g.v(1).as('f').out.as('x').out.as('y').table(t)
==>v[5]
==>v[3]
gremlin> t
==>[f:v[1], x:v[4], y:v[5]]
==>[f:v[1], x:v[4], y:v[3]]
gremlin> t.get(0,0)      
==>v[1]
gremlin> t.get(0,'x')
==>v[4]
gremlin> t.each{r->t.columnNames.each{n->println "col: " + r.getColumn(n)}}
col: v[1]
col: v[4]
col: v[5]
col: v[1]
col: v[4]
col: v[3]
==>[f:v[1], x:v[4], y:v[5]]
==>[f:v[1], x:v[4], y:v[3]]
```